# Angular :: Cascading List doesn't display the values from DB

Tags: angular, typescript, cascadingdropdown, cascading

I am new to Angular and was trying to build a project where in I have created the schemas, tables (My Sql) and APIs (using eclipse IDE) from the back end and for front end I am using Angular 9 and the VB Studio IDE.

I am struck with one of the components where in I am trying to build a cascading dropdown list (similar to Country/State/Cities) but mine is
Portfolio >> Module >> Category >> Sub Category (Portfolio is the parent table with values as Id and Name, similarly Module is linked to Portfolio (many modules belong to one portfolio - so we have Id, Module Name and Portfolio ID as the fields in Module table) and similarly Category is linked to Module and Sub Category linked to Category.
So, if we select any of the portfolio , the corresponding Modules should display and if we select a particular Module the corresponding Category should display and based on Category the Sub Category. (Seems like my foreign keys fields (Portfolio_id, module_id, category_id etc aren't getting passed or if I am missing something)

Currently based on below code - I can just see Portfolio appearing in the Drop Down and nothing else. If I remove the ID specific notations from below get methods then the entire data appears against each dropdown and the joins or binding doesn't happens.

Below is the codes : Hope someone might help me move ahead.

**component.ts file::**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { GtsformService } from 'src/app/services/gtsform.service';
//import { portfolio } from 'src/app/common/portfolio';
//import { module } from 'src/app/common/module';
//import { category } from 'src/app/common/category';
//import { subcategory } from 'src/app/common/subcategory';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gtsforms',
  templateUrl: './gtsforms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gtsforms.component.css']
})
export class GtsformsComponent implements OnInit {

  gtsforms: FormGroup;
  portfolio: {};
  module: {};
  category: {};
  subcategory: {};

  constructor(public _gtsforms: GtsformService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._gtsforms.getPortfolio()
    .subscribe(data => this.portfolio = data);

    this.gtsforms = new FormGroup({
      portfolio: new FormControl(''),
      module: new FormControl(''),
      category: new FormControl(''),
      subcategory: new FormControl('')
    });

  }
  onChangePortfolio(portfolio_id: number) {
    
    if (portfolio_id) {
      this._gtsforms.getModule(portfolio_id).subscribe(
        data => { 
          this.module = data;
          this.category = null;
          this.subcategory = null;
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.module = null;
      this.category = null;
      this.subcategory = null;
    }
  }

  onChangeModule(module_id: number) {
    if (module_id) {
      this._gtsforms.getCategory(module_id).subscribe(
        data => this.category = data
      );
    } else {
      this.category = null;
      this.subcategory = null;
    }
  }

  onChangeCategory(category_id: number) {
    if (category_id) {
      this._gtsforms.getSubcategory(category_id).subscribe(
        data => this.subcategory = data
      );
    } else {
      this.subcategory = null;
    }
  }

}
```

**service.ts file ::**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { portfolio } from '../common/portfolio';
import { module } from '../common/module';
import { category } from '../common/category';
import { subcategory } from '../common/subcategory';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GtsformService {

  public baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/";

  constructor( public http: HttpClient) { }

  getPortfolio(): Observable<portfolio[]> {
    return this.http.get<GetResponsePortfolio>(`${this.baseUrl}portfolio`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      map(response => response._embedded.portfolio)
    );
  }

  getModule(portfolio_id: number): Observable<module[]> {
    return this.http.get<GetResponseModule>(`${this.baseUrl}module/${portfolio_id}`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      map(response => response._embedded.module)
    );
  }

  getCategory(module_id: number): Observable<category[]> {
    return this.http.get<GetResponseCategory>(`${this.baseUrl}category/${module_id}`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      map(response => response._embedded.category)
    );
  }

  getSubcategory(category_id: number): Observable<subcategory[]> {
    return this.http.get<GetResponseSubcategory>(`${this.baseUrl}subcategory/${category_id}`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      map(response => response._embedded.subcategory)
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Something bad happened. Please try again later.');
  }

}

interface GetResponsePortfolio {
  _embedded: {
    portfolio: portfolio[];
  }
}
interface GetResponseModule {
  _embedded: {
    module: module[];
  }
}
interface GetResponseCategory {
  _embedded: {
    category: category[];
  }
}
interface GetResponseSubcategory {
  _embedded: {
    subcategory: subcategory[];
  }
}
```

**component.html file ::**

```
<div class="gtsforms">
  <h2>GTS Estimates</h2> <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form [formGroup]="gtsforms">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Portfolio </label>
          <select formControlName="portfolio" class="form-control" (change)="onChangePortfolio($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select portfolio...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let portfolio of portfolio" [value]="portfolio.id">{{portfolio.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Module </label>
          <select formControlName="module" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeModule($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select module...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let module of module" [value]="module.id">{{module.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category </label>
          <select formControlName="category" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCategory($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select category...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of category" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Sub Category </label>
          <select formControlName="subcategory" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select subcategory...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let subcategory of subcategory" [value]="subcategory.id">{{subcategory.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards,
Nawal Goyal

Comment: I think this is the correct behavior because initially Portfolio dropdown will only be displayed. other dropdowns are depending on each other. those will be displayed based on the value selected in the portfolio.

Comment: Thanks Durgesh, yeah that's what my qs was, although I have linked the other tables with the id's - for eg the module is linked by portfolio id , category is linked by module id, sub category is linked by category id. But still this is not working. Ideally as soon as I select a portfolio the corresponding module should appear and so on but that's not happening (although the data exists correctly in database against each tables).

Comment: Have you console the subscribed data which you get from API ? try console every data i.e. category, module, sub category and check which data is missing ? If possible then reproduce this scenario on stackblitz.

Comment: yes i am not receiving the foreign key values for any, like in the module table the portfolio id is foreign key and is coming blank, same for category table where module id is foreign key and isn't fetching any data and so for sub-category table where category id is the foreign key and isn't fetching data. Seems like something related to foreign key fields which aren't pulling data from API/database Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you test your APIs with valid parameters and responses. Try postman for sending request and debug in your backend what is missing - `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/category/module_id`